# python in visual studio

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def get_open_tickets():
    query = ("SELECT tickets.ticketid, status.status, solutions.solution, employee.name AS employee" +
            "tickets.customername, tickets.customeremail, tickets.submitteddate, tickets.issue" +
            "FROM employees INNER JOIN" +
            "tickets ON employees.employeeid = tickets.employeeid INNER JOIN" +
            "solutions ON tickets.solutionid = solutions.solutionid INNER JOIN" +
            "status ON tickets.statusid = status.statusid" +
            "WHERE tickets.statusid=1 OR tickets.statusid=2")
     with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
         cur.execute(query)
         results = cur.fetchall()
    
     tickets = []
     for row in results:
         tickets.append(make_ticket(row))
     return tickets
```

above code on visual code generates following error. please suggest a way out.

Comment: You haven't provided the error message

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, even if you didn't provide the error message:

```
SELECT tickets.ticketid, status.status, solutions.solution, employee.name AS employeetickets.customername, tickets.customeremail, tickets.submitteddate, tickets.issueFROM employees INNER JOINtickets ON employees.employeeid = tickets.employeeid INNER JOINsolutions ON tickets.solutionid = solutions.solutionid INNER JOINstatus ON tickets.statusid = status.statusidWHERE tickets.statusid=1 OR tickets.statusid=2
```

you are missing the spaces.

For example:

```
tickets.issueFROM employees
```